# Why does this lisp function return nil?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, lisp

I am trying to build a lisp function that will car and cdr through a list while comparing the values in that list to a max value. If a value in the list is larger than the max value then that value is REPLACED by the max value. I am wondering why I am getting the return value of nil? I am new to lisp and I come from a Java background so it is quite different to me. I am not allowed to use any object oriented stuff and I am limited to car, cdr, append, cons. I want to return the list "elements2".

```
(defun enforce-upper-limit(maxVal elements elements2)
(when elements
(cond ((greaterThanMax (car elements) maxVal)(enforce-upper-limit maxVal (cdr lst) (append (maxVal))))
(t   (enforce-upper-limit maxVal (cdr elements)(append (car elements)))))
)
```

)

Comment: Please format and indent your code. Your code is close to unreadable. If you ask questions you are also expected to give reproducible examples and the error message.
See the help:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What do you expect from `(append (maxVal))`, and what is the purpose of `elements2`?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Be kind.  He was starting out.

Answer (score 1):

### Formatting & naming

Common Lisp is case insensitive so your `maxVal` and `greaterThanMax` will become unreadable. Separate parts of the name with `-` and make everything lower-case.

Spaces: open parenthesis should have a space in front of it.

Indentation: this one has a various rules, but long story short: Emacs in Lisp mode will do the right thing on `<Tab>`

Finally, don't make lines too long, usual rule of 80 characters is almost universal.

After tidying it will look as follows:

```
(defun enforce-upper-limit (max-val elements elements2)
  (when elements
    (cond ((greater-than-max (car elements) max-val)
           (enforce-upper-limit max-val (cdr lst) (append (max-val))))
          (t (enforce-upper-limit max-val (cdr elements)
                                          (append (car elements))))))
```

### Problems in the code

Some obvious problems:

1. Line 4: expression `(max-val)` will call a function called `max-val` with no arguments. I doubt this is what you want.
2. Function `append` appends lists. In both cases of its use it is neither given a list to append nor it has a list to append to.
3. Function `enforce-upper-limit` at best will return `nil`.
4. What is `lst`? Probably should be `elements`.

Let's start fixing. First, let's deal with problem 3. When `elements` is `nil`, the answer should be accumulated in `elements2`. Also, the whole conditional expression resembles `if... elseif ...` pattern. So, let's try to arrange it in one `cond`:

```
(defun enforce-upper-limit (max-val elements elements2)
  (cond ((null elements) elements2)
        ((greater-than-max (car elements) max-val)
         (enforce-upper-limit max-val (cdr lst) (append (max-val))))
        (t (enforce-upper-limit max-val (cdr elements)
                                        (append (car elements)))))
```

Next, let's see what we actually want to achieve. The second clause states that if `(car elements)` is too large, `max-val` should go to `elements2`. And if `(car elements)` is OK (the last clause), it is added to `elements2`.

Adding one item to the list is the job for `cons`, not `append`. In both cases we are consing to `elements2` so expression should look like `(cons something elements2)`. Also, replacement of `lst` with `elements` produces (almost) correct program:

```
   (defun enforce-upper-limit (max-val elements elements2)
      (cond ((null elements) elements2)
            ((greater-than-max (car elements) max-val)
             (enforce-upper-limit max-val
                                  (cdr elements)
                                  (cons max-val elements2)))
            (t (enforce-upper-limit max-val (cdr elements)
                                            (cons (car elements) elements2)))))
```

### Further issues

- Not sure if there is a need in `greater-than-max` as simple `>` will suffice.
- Items in `elements2` are in a wrong order compared to `elements` (I leave it up to you to figure that out). This is a usual problem of iterative algorithms on lists.

Finally, more CL way of doing it would be

```
(defun enforce-upper-limit (list max-val)
  (loop for x in list
        if x > max-val
          collect max-val
        else
          collect x))
```

but it might not be acceptable for your assignment.